# Is it possible to convert a Max heap to a Min heap in place?

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures

I was just wondering if this was possible?

Surely there maybe some naive methods of doing so, but I was just wondering if someone can suggest efficient ways to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by “convert a Max heap to a Min heap in place”?

Comment: Let's see if I remember... :) A "heap" is a data structure that holds numbers (usually, plus some data associated with them). It's always a complete binary tree (as much as possible), so it can be stored in an array. A "max heap" is a tree where the children are always at most their father. A "min heap" is a tree where the children are always at least their father. "In place" means not copying the data as an intermediate step, without using more space than the space of the existing heap.

Comment: @Dana: Thank you for a reply.  I thought that the question might be about using the code for a Max heap to implement a Min heap (which was trivial).

Comment: @Dana: Thanks for the detailed explanation on the problem :). And yes, everything you said is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just ignore that you have a max heap and build your min heap from it. O(n) time
complexity. No need for additional array.

Comment: Yes, the key thing here is that an arbitrary array can be converted into a heap in $O(n)$ time in place.

Comment: Could you please explain how it's O(n) or provide the steps in converting. If I start treating the Max heap as min heap, I think it's O(n)log(n), maybe I am not able to visualize it.

Comment: Search for "Heapify" in Cormen-Leiserson-Rivest book.

Comment: @Gunner, see here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Min_and_Max_Heaps#Inserting_a_value_into_the_heap

Comment: @slimton: Doesn't the heapify operation take O(nlogn)?

Comment: @Gunner. Perhaps I should have said "look for Build-heap" in CRS. It takes O(n) time. The point is that each element takes time proportional to its height to find its place in the heap, so the total running time is $\sum_{h = 1}^{\log_2 n} \Theta(h) n/2^h$, which is $O(n)$.

Comment: Ok I understand now.